# Set environment variable at the project level

Tags: pydev

Using PyDev with Eclipse Juno, I need to set some environment variables to debug every single of the many scripts in my project. I have found how to set them for a given script but it would be totally impractical to do it for all of them. The only solution I have found consists in adding those variable to the Python interpreter configuration in the Preferences. But then it will be used by all projects, which I don't want.

I thought of creating a script setting those environment variables and then launching Python, and then add it as a new Python interpreter but PyDev does not accept two interpreters with the same actual exe (I guess it checks sys.executable).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is really setting it at the Python interpreter level.

You can use virtualenv ( http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv ) to create a copy of your interpreter in a different path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But imho PyDev should allow such per-project properties.

Comment: Humm... yes, but things may be tricky in that respect... i.e.: say you have projects A, B, C and A and B have an env var "X" with different values and C depends on both projects, which value would be used for "X" in that situation? If you have an acceptable solution which is not conflicting in that situation, please create a feature-request in the PyDev tracker (see: http://pydev.org/about.html for links)

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate that @FabioZadrozny's answer meets the need of the OP...

In case it hasn't occurred to you, do this:

- From the menu "Window->Preference"
- Navigate to "PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter"
- Create a new interpreter instance with "New..." button
- Name it something like "python-MyProj", but use the same executable you are already using
- Now in the "Environment" tab for that interpreter, set up the needed environment variable

Now, see the PyDev project to use THAT interpreter:

- Right-click the project to get "Properties..."
- Navigate to "PyDev-Interpreter/Grammar"
- Select the newly created interpreter instance by name

Now run any python file within the project, and it should "see" the configured environment variable.

By this mechanism, you *do* have a "project specific setting"... which, again, for the reasons @FabioZadrozny pointed out, *need* to be set at the interpreter level.